# Bootstrap CSS: Maintain card button position when browser dimensions change

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create cards that maintain the position of its button when the user's browser dimensions change.

Desktop full-screen:
[image: full width available with "upvote" button on right]

When the browser is resized:
[image: narrower browser window with "upvote" button reflowed to bottom]

I'm trying to keep the card button in the same position when the browser is resized. But in my example the "Upvote" button is moved beneath the text, instead of remaining on the right side. To be more specific, have a look at this picture:

[image: marked up image showing reserved space for "upvote" button on right]

The green space should be reserved for the button, and red space should be the position of the button:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div>
<div class="container">
      <div class="card m-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="container p-1">
            <img
              src="https://1iq2pi1r3dw63rcvw63p8mfb-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/kion-bar-box-600x600.jpg"
              class="float-left mr-1"
              alt=""
              width="60px"
              heigth="60px"
            />
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-11 pr-5">
                <h5 class="card-title">Kion Bar 2 - Best energy bar there is no</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Best energy bar there is, no other like this that can even..</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 ml-md-auto align-self-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary float-right">
                  Upvote
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Essentially, you would have to **set** a fixed height.

Comment: You are not using the grid correctly. The hierarchy to follow is .container > .row > .col-x. You have row outside of container. It needs to be inside. The .row class should immediately be followed by a .col-x class. You should NEVER have a .container within a .container. Lastly, you're trying to use flex elements (but never declare flex for the parent) in conjunction with float. The two are completely different and do not work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="media align-items-center">
          <img width="10%" class="align-self-center mr-3" src="https://1iq2pi1r3dw63rcvw63p8mfb-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/kion-bar-box-600x600.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-md-9 col-9">
                <h5 class="mt-0">Kion Bar 2 - Best energy bar there is no</h5>
                <p>Best energy bar there is, no other like this that can even..</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-3">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary float-right">
                  Upvote
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It'd be better if you use media, it'll make your work easier. Also `.container` should use only once within a section.

- Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s
  contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or
  .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device
  sizes.
- Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
  (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This
  padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This
  way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the
  left side.
- In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
  columns may be immediate children of rows.

You can check the below links for reference

[Grid System of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

[Media](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/)

Comment: This worked much better than cards, after including a border. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are making many mistakes in your markup. You should take the time to learn how to correctly write your markup.

Secondly, learn how to work with images. DO use width and height attributes for your images, but DO NOT specify them in pixels. What you are doing is setting an aspect ratio, not the actual dimensions. The .img-fluid class makes your image responsive. The attributes maintains its aspect ratio. Specifying the aspect ratio will prevent the browser from moving content down the page while it waits to download the image and figure out how to draw it on the canvas.

I believe the following is what you are trying to do.

[See it on Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/rkl9BWqXxm)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card my-2">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
          <img src="https://1iq2pi1r3dw63rcvw63p8mfb-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/kion-bar-box-600x600.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="" width="600" heigth="600">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <h5 class="card-title">Kion Bar 2 - Best energy bar there is no</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Best energy bar there is, no other like this that can even..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block">
            Upvote
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember, you can set different col spans for different viewports.